# Compute probability from joint density function

Tags: probability, multivariable-calculus, probability-distributions, density-function

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two random variables with joint density function $f(x,y) = x+y, \ 0 \leq x, y \leq 1,$ zero elsewhere. Find $\mathbb{P}(X<2Y).$

As of now what I think I have an idea of how to do it but I'm not certain. I need to do a double integral of $(x+y) dx \ dy$ with the inner integral (the one with dx) spanning from 0 to 2y and the outer integral spanning from 0 to 1? Am I right to do it this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea you have is correct - you can get $\mathbb{P}(X < 2Y)$ by integrating $f(x,y)$ over the region where $X<2Y$ is true.

First draw the unit square. Over it draw the line segment where $x=2y.$ It connects the points $(0,0)$ and $(1, 1/2).$ The portion of the square above this line is where $ X<2Y.$ In this region, $x$ varies between $0$ and $1$ and for a fixed $x,$ $y$ varies from $x/2$ to $1.$ So the integral you want is

$$ \mathbb{P}(X<2Y) = \int^1_0 \int^{1}_{x/2} f(x,y) dy dx $$

Comment: Do you know how I can express these bounds in terms of Y? Like I totally get what you did since X<2y then x/2 < y so its a lower limit and 1 is the stated upper limit but I'm trying to express my integral in terms of Y instead for the sake of it


Like  outerbounds: [0, 1] innerbounds: [0, 2y] f(x,y) dxdy but it just doesn't come up the same with wolfram alpha. I've tried messing around with the parameters more but can't come up with anything but I'm certain an equivalent integral does like exist so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: also shouldn't your inner integral actually be [x/2 , .5] ?

Comment: You described a square with the corners (0,0) and (1, 1/2) but the upper limit in that square is 1/2.  Now i'm inclined to believe you're right because when I did the calculation with your integral I got the same answer as the other guy who answered but then what am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: @imarben007 The region where $ X < 2Y$ is the region shaded grey [here](https://imgur.com/KlMRcyH). Does this clear things up?

Comment: yeah I was trying to figure out my drawings for so long and yeah this totally confirms what I finally figured out seconds ago, and now that I know the region I figured out what it looks like to change the region of integration for this problem! Thank you so much man!

Comment: @imarben007 No worries. Glad you kept at it until you understood it :)

Answer (score 1):

[The PDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_distribution#Derivation) of $Z:=X/Y$, which has support $[0,\,\infty)$, is$$\int_0^1yf(zy,\,y)dy=\int_0^{\min\{1/z,\,1\}}y^2(z+1)dy=\frac13(z+1)[\min\{1/z,\,1\}]^3.$$So$$\begin{align}P(Z<2)&=\int_0^2\frac13(z+1)[\min\{1/z,\,1\}]^3dz\\&=\int_0^1\frac13(z+1)dz+\int_1^2\frac13(z^{-2}+z^{-3})dz\\&=\frac12+\frac13[-z^{-1}-z^{-2}/2]_1^2\\&=\frac{19}{24}.\end{align}$$[Python agrees](https://repl.it/repls/SuperficialEachSite).

Comment: are you sure this is the method to do it? I haven't seen a problem solved like this before so i do not know what Z:= x/y which has support [0, infinity] is meant to mean.  honestly i don't understand most of your work.

Comment: shouldn't there be double integrals in this?

Comment: @imarven007 The original problem is equivalent to $P(Z<2)$, which is a single integral in terms of $Z$'s PDF. The support of $Z$ is its set of possible values. So yes, it's a standard method for the distribution of a ratio of two variables.